# Can't do git fsck inflate data stream error (incorrect data check) in remote bare repository

Tags: git

I'm getting this error on my private (bare) repository. I really don't know why this happened, I restored the repository using an automatic server backup:

```
bash-4.1$ git fsck
error: inflate: data stream error (incorrect data check)
error: corrupt loose object '08a710268f35b6c1c65d5fa6669840689814efbc'
fatal: object 08a710268f35b6c1c65d5fa6669840689814efbc is corrupted
```

Repository has two branches: `master` and `next`.

I can't `git clone` on my development machine because I'm getting a corrupt loose object error and I haven't a fully local repository of the project. I may be able to find some original files but how can I guess which file belongs to that object?

By the way, on the bare repository `git log --oneline`works:

```
bash-4.1$ git log --oneline
ea338b8 Fix singledaterangepicker con valore
caf4f79 Fix margini container quando dentro colonne
d2f98dc Aggiornamento versione bower.json
f18138e Risolto problema singledaterangepicker e altri fix
538abc7 Lock versione Bootstrap per colorpicker
990484b Risolto errore cartella bower
0bf08d6 Fix mismatch versione
296a78c Fix sezione main e versione
e400378 Initial commit
```

I'm only interested in the latest commit of both branch, not the full history. Any way to recover my data?